# Angular external library is always initializing

Tags: angular-library, angular13

I am importing a reusable library in my app.module.ts file.
The library has an interface for options like, api url, custom providers etc.
The problem is that the component in the library is initializing regardless and my custom providers will then execute and i have no control.
The library is working in a new app, there i can declare the component from the library in my component template, but not in my existing app.